# struts 2 and sitemesh localization

Tags: struts2, localization, sitemesh

i am using struts 2 and sitemesh. I can change locale in my login page without problem just by setting a request parameter named with 'request_locale' parameter. But in all other pages i am using sitemesh for decorating header and footer. And i tried to set same parameter for other pages but no luck. These are some of the other codes that i tried in my Login Action:

```
request.getSession(false).setAttribute("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE", newLocale);
ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(newLocale);
session.put(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, newLocale);
```

When i write out these settings i see everything is ok.
But when i write out

```
<c:out value="${pageContext.request.locale.language}"/>
```

it is always showing browsers Accept-Language and it doesnt make any localization.
How can i make localization to work with sitemesh?

Comment: So everything is working you just don't know how to show current locale in JSP?

Comment: No after login i redirect to index.jsp page. But page is rendered with default language of the browser. I am searching now if it is because of redirect to page. I will try to redirect to action.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to redirect from login action to an action named home with request locale parameter and then this action redirects to index.jsp. Everything is ok now. 
And i set default action as home action so when user enters root page from address bar it is activing home action so i18n interceptor and intercoptors are becaming active.
This is login.action in struts.xml:

```
<action name="login" class="wateron.login.LoginAction" >
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">home?request_locale=${request_locale}</param>
            <param name="namespace">/</param>
        </result> 
</action>
```

And this is home action in struts.xml :

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="">
    <default-action-ref name="home" />
    <action name="home">
        <result>/index.jsp</result>     
    </action>
</package>
```

Thanks for reference question :
[How to use interceptor on the default page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522350/how-to-use-interceptor-on-the-default-page)